# Yukawa Couplings of Fermions to Higgs Field

Tags: standard-model, higgs, interactions, electroweak

*Context*: The Yukawa couplings of fermions to the Higgs field are given by $$g_{f} = \sqrt{2}\frac{m_{f}}{v}.$$

*Question*: In his book "Modern Particle Physics", Mark Thomson writes on page 486:

> Interestingly,  for the top quark with $m_{t}\sim 173.5 \pm 1.0$ GeV, the Yukawa coupling is almost unity. Whilst this may be a coincidence, it is perhaps natural that the Yukawa couplings of the fermions are $\mathcal O(1)$.

I don't understand this last statement. Excluding neutrinos (whose small mass is really exceptional), if we just take electrons or muons, their Yukawa coupling is certainly NOT $\mathcal O(1)$..

Comment: Ach... "natural" is a highly [technical and fraught term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalness_(physics)), only loosely aligning with one's intuitive sense... My sense is you might shrug this one off and move on to things that matter...

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That certainly saves time. :)

Comment: The only way to make such couplings "natural" is by a comprehensive mechanism to generate the electoweak scale $v$ that we do not have, presently.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_quark_condensate) that links the Higgs to the top quark mass and suggests that  the Higgs is a top quark condensate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right that for electrons or muons, their Yukawa coupling is certainly NOT $O(1)$. You can have two interpretations of Mark Thomson's remark:

1. The ratio of electron mass vs top quark mass is around $10^{-5}$. It is certainly NOT $O(1)$, but it is not as bad as $10^{-20}$ when comparing fermion mass with Planck mass. So Mark Thomson means that the Yukawa couplings are *roughly* $O(1)$.
2. Mark Thomson actually means that the top Yukawa coupling is *naturally* $O(1)$, while the other Yukawa coupling are NOT natural, but he does not want to get into much speculations in his book. As the other answer pointed out, in the hypothetical [top-condensation model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_quark_condensate), the top quark-antiquark pair condensates and plays the role of Higgs field. In this case, top quark mass is of order of the electroweak scale. So the top Yukawa coupling is *naturally* $O(1)$. That said, the original top-condensation model does not address the problem of why other fermion mass is much smaller than top mass. Note that there are some extensions of top-condensation model which attempted to address this issue.

Comment: Concerning your remark 1.: That would be a *very* rough approximation. :) Thanks for your answer.